# Por que o laço não imprime até o último valor que foi entrado como limite?

Tags: javascript, html, while, condição

Fiz um código que imprime uma sequência de números, do número digitado até o final, porém ao imprimí-la o último número não está aparecendo.

Exemplo: primeiro número digitado é 3 e o segundo é 7. A sequência ficaria 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, porém o 7 não aparece.

```js
function id(valor_campo)
  {
    return document.getElementById(valor_campo);
  }

function getValor(valor_campo)
  {
    var valor = document.getElementById(valor_campo).value;
    return (valor);
  }

function nums(valores)
  { 
    var inicio = getValor("num1");
    var fim = getValor("num2");
    var res = 0;
    while (inicio < fim)
    {
      res += (inicio)+"<br>";
      inicio++;

    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
  }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    
    Valor 1: <input type="number" name="num1" id="num1"> <br><br>

    Valor 2: <input type="number" name="num2" id="num2"> <br><br>

    <button onclick="nums()">Saiba a sequência dos números digitados!</button>

    <p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 2):

O problema é o operador de comparação. Você está mandando repetir enquanto o valor da variável de controle `inicio` seja menor que `fim`, então vai terminar um número antes, porque no momento que for igual já não é menor, é igual. Se quer que o último seja impresso, ou seja, que ele seja inclusivo tem que usar o operador menor ou igual (`<=`), assim:

```js
function id(valor_campo) { return document.getElementById(valor_campo); }

function getValor(valor_campo) { return document.getElementById(valor_campo).value; }

function nums(valores) {   
    var inicio = getValor("num1");
    var fim = getValor("num2");
    var res = 0;
    while (inicio <= fim) res += inicio++ + "<br>";
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
```

```html
Valor 1: <input type="number" name="num1" id="num1"> <br><br>

Valor 2: <input type="number" name="num2" id="num2"> <br><br>

<button onclick="nums()">Saiba a sequência dos números digitados!</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/EndLoop.js).

Comment: Com certeza, faz todo sentido.

Fico muito agradecido pela ajuda, Maniero!

Abraço!

Answer (score 1):

Como dito acima, o problema está no operador de comparação, basta substituir o `<` por `<=`.

Acredito que talvez você esteja iniciando no JavaScript, se sim, legal cara, você começou de uma maneira interessante, já separando seu código em funções para reaproveitamento de código. E caso você esteja realmente no início, uma dica seria você já iniciar com os novos padrões, mas essa é outra história kk. Fiz algumas melhorias no seu código, caso queira dar uma observada vou deixar abaixo.

```
function id (valor_campo)
{
  return document.getElementById(valor_campo);
}

function getValor (valor_campo)
{
  var valor = id(valor_campo).value; // Utilizando a Função id que você criou
  return (valor);
}

function nums () // retirando o parametro que não estava sendo usado
{   
  var inicio = getValor("num1");
  var fim = getValor("num2");
  var res = ''; // tirando o 0 que era impresso e inserindo uma string vazia, pois não é exibida
  while (inicio <= fim) // Arrumando o bug do operado
  {
    res += (inicio)+"<br>";
    inicio++;
  }
  id("demo").innerHTML = res; // utilizando mais uma vez a sua função
}
```

Comment: Opa, tudo certo Eduardo?

Isso mesmo, estou iniciando sim no JavaScript.

Fico muito agradecido pela ajuda sua!

Abs